# Wordpress category query not working

Tags: php, if-statement

I want to get the category from the current archive page with

```
<?php single_cat_title( '', true ); ?>
```

So i defined `$thecat = single_cat_title( '', true );`

and now I am trying only to echo something if the category isn't the current one.

```
<?php if($thecat !== "Stuff") { echo'<li><a href="/stuff"> Stuff</a></li>';}?>
```

But it is not working.. what is wrong here?

Comment: Try `$thecat = single_cat_title('', false)`?

Comment: ohh thank you.. too easy :) You can post it as an answer. I will accept it then.

Comment: There are a lot of similar things in WordPress, and the functions are (*sigh*) slightly inconsistent; on the other hand, the documentation is very good, so it's worth bookmarking the codex as a reference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there.

Have a look at [the manual page for `single_cat_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_cat_title), you'll see that it takes two parameters. The first is a prefix to use in the return; the second is the important one here - it defines whether you want the category to be echoed out (if `true`), or returned (if `false`). So all you need to do is swap:

```
$thecat = single_cat_title( '', true );
```

to:

```
$thecat = single_cat_title( '', false );
```

In your current code, you're just echoing the title, and `$thecat` is being set to `null`.